# Unity: Provider a Func<> to instantiate a specific interface implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

We are having a WPF application with Unity, and I've just one case, were I've to work with one of our library. This library provide us one service that we would like to use in our ViewModel, but the way to create it through a "ServiceContainer" on its own.

I would like to register this service within Unity, would that be possible?

To do something like this?

```
ServiceContainer serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer(..., ..., ...);
unityContainer.RegisterType<IDialogService>(()=> serviceContainer.GetService<IDialogService>());
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ServiceContainer serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer(..., ..., ...);

container.RegisterType<IDialogService>(
            new InjectionFactory(c => serviceContainer.GetService<IDialogService>()));
```

This is the `InjectionFactory` see this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec19)

The example in the article is:

```
container
  .RegisterType<ISurveyAnswerStore, SurveyAnswerStore>(
    new InjectionFactory((c, t, s) => new SurveyAnswerStore(
      container.Resolve<ITenantStore>(),
      container.Resolve<ISurveyAnswerContainerFactory>(),
      container.Resolve<IMessageQueue<SurveyAnswerStoredMessage>>(
        new ParameterOverride(
          "queueName", Constants.StandardAnswerQueueName)),
      container.Resolve<IMessageQueue<SurveyAnswerStoredMessage>>(
        new ParameterOverride(
          "queueName", Constants.PremiumAnswerQueueName)),
      container.Resolve<IBlobContainer<List<string>>>())));
```

You see how the lambda for `new InjectionFactory((c, t, s) => ...` where `c` is the container, so you can ask the container for other types at the point of type creation.

### Why is this helpful

If you want to supply `new ServiceContainer(..., ..., ...);` with arguments from your container then:

```
container
    .RegisterType<IDialogService>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
    { 
        var arg1 = c.Resolve<IArg1>();
        var arg2 = c.Resolve<IArg2>();
        var arg3 = c.Resolve<IArg3>();

        ServiceContainer serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer(arg1, arg2, arg3);

        serviceContainer.GetService<IDialogService>()
    }));
```

Comment: No problem, my pleasure